# How can I use an html file inside a conditional comment for IE?

Tags: html, css

What I want to do is to check through a conditional comment if a user is using IE6,7 or 8 and if he does then I want to load a different html file than my index.php.

I have been instructed to use a javascript like the one below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(body).html('Please download firefox or chrome to view this site');});
```

and then use the normal conditional comment structure with  tag including the js file, but for some reason this doesn't work.

Additionally as I said above I want to redirect the users in a new html file ex.main.html instead of index.php, if they are using IE as their browser. I do not want to use html code inside the comment, I want to somehow force the user be redirected to the new file.

Any ideas or guidance will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution, without JavaScript would look like this (put this in your `<head>`):

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://example.com/ie.html" /><![endif]-->
```

This would redirect the user to `http://example.com/ie.html` (Just replace that part with the actual URL). Advantage of this solution: It does also work, if the user has **deactivated JavaScript**.

Answer (score 2):

For a redirect in jQuery you could use:

```
$(window.location).attr('href', 'http://www.stackoverflow.com');
```

Or in plain JavaScript:

```
window.location.href='http://www.stackoverflow.com';
```

Comment: What would the structure of the above JavaScript look like? Do I need to put the code in a ready function or what?

Comment: You can place it in a `.ready()` method, but then your redirect happens first when the DOM has been fully constructed what you wouldn't need here. Have a look at JavaScripts `onload` event, that's what I would recommend you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`jQuery.browser`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) method to determeine the browser being used.

**Example:**

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
    alert("this is IE :(");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
span:only-of-type {
    display: none;
}
span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: -150px 0 0 -150px;
    background: black;
}
```

…

```
<span>Dude, get a real browser!</span>
```